# Diff indices in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes, I need to add new fields to an index in ElasticSearch. When I do this, I create a new index, update its mapping, reindex into this new index, and then swap the aliases with the old index before deleting the old index.

It is really easy to verify if the counts are same between the old index and the new index, but in the event that counts don't match, it has been a rather ad-hoc process of finding exactly which documents are missing. Is it possible to quickly diff the two indices(or the document ids in the indices)?

Comment: You know you can add new fields to your mapping on-the-fly, without reindexing, right? http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/

Comment: Matt, the linked article actually mentions the workflow that I mentioned, with moving aliases between indices.

Comment: Right – I just meant that if you're strictly _adding_ fields, you don't need to go through all those steps.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but no I am not strictly adding fields.

Comment: What solution did you end up with? I am looking for exactly the same feature.

Comment: If you don't have new documents added into the old index from the time you start scan and scroll, it is very unlikely you will lose any documents. I originally had the same issue. I realized later that I forgot to do a flush after reindexing. A flush is a fsync so all data is written to disk.

Comment: @foresightyj I haven't figured out a good way yet, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think there exists such a way. Probably we need to sort this out in the application by scan&scroll all Ids.