# Elasticsearch how can I do online re-index without missing newly documents after scan & scoll?

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't want my elasticsearch to be taken offline while re-indexing (using scan and scoll api), so my strategy is re-indexing online and in the end check if the number of documents in the new index is not less than the old index. Note, I did a flush after re-index so document counts are correct.

However, as I am re-indexing, new documents are added to the old index. So in the end of re-index, some documents are missing (which aren't actually missing, they were just added after the start of re-indexing).

I don't dare to alias the new index to the official index name at the start of re-index. Because, in the case where there are actually documents missing, all newly added documents during re-index will be in the new index. I want the effect that if the new index fails, I can simply delete it without affecting the old index.

This won't be a problem if I could either diff two indices or if I could retrieve all documents which were added after some checkpoint time.

I saw a post at [Diff indices in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856533/diff-indices-in-elasticsearch) which asks how to diff two indices but no answers to that.

Comment: Why aren't you able to add the new documents to the new index while you are reindexing instead of continuing to add new docs to the old index? Why are you afraid the reindexing will fail? Maybe you could consider a route to separate new docs from reindeer ones in the new index. That way if it does fail, you could use the route to pull only those docs added that were new,. Never tried that but seems feasible.

Comment: Your suggestion seems feasible. Thanks.
As for why I am afraid that reindexing will fail, I am just worried that the network will fail or timeout between scrolls.

Comment: I actually worked out a ugly implementation yesterday. I took advantage of a "CreateTime" property in 3 out of 4 types I have in my index. At the end of the reindex, I simply scan and scroll all documents that are added after CreateTime and re-add them into the new index. If the counts still don't match, I will delete the new index and retry. Luckily the frequency of insertion of new documents isn't that high right now so this works reasonably OK.